# View logrotated log continuously

Tags: logging

Is there a command to view logrotated logs as a continuous stream with proper ordering?

I need to view all entries in syslog in historical order starting from the oldest entry available. So far I was inspecting logs one by one manually.

```
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm             140368 Jun 12 09:41 syslog
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              45498 Jun 12 06:25 syslog.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               1874 Jun 11 06:25 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               1758 Jun 10 06:25 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm               1615 Jun  9 06:25 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              28494 Jun  8 06:25 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              92359 Jun  7 06:53 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog    adm              13849 Jun  6 09:21 syslog.7.gz
```

Comment: journalctl doesn't work in your scenario ?

Comment: @Marged are you sure that `journalctl` includes all info from `syslog` for postmortem analysis? I've got an impression that `syslog` is independent of `systemd/journalctl` and it is written even if those both are killed, for example with out of memory.

Comment: I wouldn't bet money on it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If all the files are there without any extension then yes you can execute the cat command with * (cat *) it will display the content of each and every files underneath this directory, but here in your output it has the zip files (*.gz) too, so you need to execute 2 commands rather than single command...

1. cat syslog syslog.1
2. zcat *.gz

Hope this will helps.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the proper ordering, right?